# What are the default color codes of angular material dark-theme

Tags: angular, angular-material

Does anyone know what are the default color codes of angulars material dark theme?
especially the color code of the mat input without focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information related to theming can be found under [here](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/material/core/theming).

The file [_palette.scss](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/core/theming/_palette.scss) contains the color codes which may be the main of importance.

Lastly, the color code of the mat input can be accessed by just using the browsers color picker. Without more details on what you want, it is not possible to provide the color (do you want the background color, the font color, the border colour?).